# use to matrix and double pointer

Tags: c

The size of the square matrix is entered as standard input (the range of input values is 2 to 10). Create a program that prints the unit matrix of the input size.

The unit matrix is a matrix whose diagonal from the top left to the bottom right (main diagonal) is 1 and all others are zero.

ex) input: 5

result :

```
1 0 0 0 0\n
0 1 0 0 0\n
0 0 1 0 0\n
0 0 0 1 0\n
0 0 0 0 1\n
```

my code:

```
int main(){
int n;


scanf("%d", &n);

int **matrix = malloc(sizeof(int *) * n);

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    matrix[i] = malloc(sizeof(int) * n);
    memset(matrix[i], 0, sizeof(int) * n);
}

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    matrix[i][i] = 1;
    printf("%d ", matrix[i][i]);
}
printf("\n");



for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
      free(matrix[i]);


}

free(matrix);

return 0;
}
```

.. what 's the error?

Comment: What does the code print and how does it differ from what you expect?

Comment: You might like to read this: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a double loop to print the output:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    matrix[i][i] = 1;  // set identity
}

for (int j=0; j<n; j++)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", matrix[j][i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: Do you think he really needs 2d array to print `unit matrix` ?

Comment: @hoon In that case this is the answer that you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

One error is to think yo need a data strucure to print the output requested.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int n;
    if (scanf("%d", &n) != 1 || n < 2 || 10 < n) {
        perror("Input error!\n\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        for (int k = 0; k < n; ++k)
            printf(i == k ? "1 " : "0 ");
        putchar('\n');
    }
}
```